# Making a simple quiz game. Stuck with the arrays part

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a game with 2 views, the first view has buttons which segues to another view. Depending on the segue identifier, it loads an image which the player has to guess.
I also have a an array which lists hints for the 4 images.
With the array, i made a button which shows the hints on the view, but the problem I have right now is that I don't know how to set the correct array to the image/puzzle.

A code that works right now is this:

```
if ([self.thePuzzle.name  isEqual: @"lion"])
{
NSArray *hints = [lines[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
self.hintLabel.text = hints[0];
}
```

But after adding another line for the second image/puzzle, the app crashes.

2nd UPDATE: code that crashes

After entering this code

```
if ([self.thePuzzle.name  isEqual: @"penguin"])
{
NSArray *hints = [lines[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
self.hintLabel.text = hints[1];
}
```

The hint button works for the 1st code, which has the lion picture, while the second part of the code, for the penguin pic, crashes when the Hint button is pressed.

3rd Update: Additional information

I made xcode access a file from the internet which contained the words for my array.

This is how i coded it.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.thePuzzle.imgFileName];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://m.uploadedit.com/b032/1395295852132.txt";

```
NSString *contents = [TextFileManager readStringFromURL:urlString];

//parse contents
lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for( int i = 0; i < lines.count; i++)

{

    NSString *line = lines[i];
    NSLog(@"%d: %@", i, line);
}
```

Comment: Show the code that crashes and the stack trace from the crash.  (It's hard to guess the problem by looking at code that works the way you want it to.)

Comment: after the crash, this error code comes up This error comes up                                                       #import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
 THREAD 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: That's not really the error location.  For some dumb reason Xcode likes to show the first like of code in the app when it gets an unhandled exception.  Go to the Breakpoint Navigator view and add a breakpoint on exceptions.  That should show you a more useful stack trace.  There should also be a console error message that would mean more than "SIGABRT".

Comment: Well, this appears in the console                                   014-03-20 22:11:58.151 SuperFinalProject[50956:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: this appears at the end of the console:  22  UIKit                               0x0022ed3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
 23  SuperFinalProject                   0x0000380d main + 141
 24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d79725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Instea of using `isEqual`, use `isEqualToString` when comparing strings.

Comment: It's tell you you're accessing an empty array.

Comment: I tried changing it to isEqualToString. Still crashes with the penguin hint button.

Comment: Use NSLog to display the contents of `lines` and `hints` before using `[1]` on them.  The error is saying that you only have an object at `[0]` when you try to access the second one.

Comment: Hmm. I don't quite get it. Does printing the contents in the console count?

Comment: I don't exactly know where to put the code. Should i place it before NSArray *hints?

Comment: Okay guys. Played around with the code, and now it works. From              if ([self.thePuzzle.name  isEqual: @"penguin"])
    {
    NSArray *hints = [lines[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];
    self.hintLabel.text = hints[1];
    }                                                                           To                                                        ([self.thePuzzle.name  isEqual: @"penguin"])
    {
    self.hintLabel.text = hints[1];
    }